# вызов функции один раз python

Tags: python, классы, функции, singleton

Здравствуйте. Возник такой вопрос как в python вызывать функцию один раз и дальше работать с её данными (singleton вроде называется такой подход).
У меня имеется функция `jsonApi` которая получает данные с сайта. Мне нужно запустить её один раз при старте программы и дальше уже работать с её переменными. Но сейчас каждый раз когда я обращаюсь к переменной `jsonResponse` у меня функция вызывается заново.

```
def jsonApi():
    url_api = urllib.request.urlopen('http://site.ru').read()
    jsonResponse = json.loads(url_api.decode('utf-8'))
    return jsonResponse

def searchJsonText(searchText):
    jsonResponse = jsonApi()
    for searchWord in jsonResponse:
        string1 = searchWord['H_NAME']
        if not string1 == None:  
            if string1.lower() == searchText.lower():
                H_ID = searchWord['H_ID']
                break
    return H_ID
```

Comment: Одиночка (singleton) — это экземпляр какого-нибудь класса, а не функция.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так вынесете вызов из функции `searchJsonText` и добавьте ей в параметры вызова результат работы `jsonApi()`.
Например:

```
def jsonApi():
    url_api = urllib.request.urlopen('http://site.ru').read()
    jsonResponse = json.loads(url_api.decode('utf-8'))
    return jsonResponse

jsonResp = jsonApi()

def searchJsonText(jsonResp, searchText):
    for searchWord in jsonResp:
        string1 = searchWord['H_NAME']
        if not string1 == None:  
            if string1.lower() == searchText.lower():
                H_ID = searchWord['H_ID']
                break
    return H_ID
```

Если я правильно понял, то вам это нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так лучше всего:

```
import functools


@functools.lru_cache()
def jsonApi():
    url_api = urllib.request.urlopen('http://site.ru').read()
    jsonResponse = json.loads(url_api.decode('utf-8'))
    return jsonResponse

def searchJsonText(searchText):
    jsonResponse = jsonApi()
    for searchWord in jsonResponse:
        string1 = searchWord['H_NAME']
        if not string1 == None:  
            if string1.lower() == searchText.lower():
                H_ID = searchWord['H_ID']
                break
    return H_ID
```